# What is the best sdk for Facebook in Python?

Tags: python, facebook

Since the facebook Python SDK has been officially deprecated ([link](https://github.com/facebook/python-sdk)). What is the best way to implement an app that will download all the data of a particular user using Python with his permissions?

Thanks.

Comment: Were you able to get anything to work?

Comment: Yeah this works [fbconsole](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole/)

Comment: For posting photos to Facebook as well?  I've just tried fbconsole two days ago and although I can post a status update, when I try to post a photo I get “HTTPError: HTTP Error 400: Bad Request” returned from fbconsole.  What's your experience with that?  (and yes, I have publish_stream privileges).

Comment: Never tried posting Photos. You can file a bug or contact the author of fbconsole, he might be able to help you.

Answer (score 2):

"Best" is very subjective. A good option is [PyFacebook](https://github.com/sciyoshi/pyfacebook/).

Comment: Does it fix the issue of "the new cookie format" that facebook has rolled out which is why Official SDK was deprecated.
Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelMior Not sure how that can be given the last commit to PyFacebook is a year ago.  Nothing about the deprecation of the Facebook/Python-SDK is listed on that page.

Comment: @Chelonian Good point. I haven't tried PyFacebook recently, so you might be right.

Answer (score 1):

I found [this](https://github.com/facebook/fbconsole/) and it worked quite well for me. Allows me to add permissions on the fly and worked pretty well till now.
Thanks.